# Прикрепить объект к пользователю из списка друзей

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Имеется модель User:

```
has_many :shipments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', 
                                 :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Модель Friendship:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
```

Модель Shipment:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Как сделать так, что бы пользователь (User) создавая объект Shipment мог выбрать одного пользователя из списка друзей и прикрепить его к модели Shipment?

Например: Пользователь-1 (User) создает модель (Shipment) и прикрепляет к ней своего друга (Friendship) Пользователя-2 (User) - которого выбирает из выпадающего списка своих друзей.

Comment: Это вообще возможно или может гемом каким-то реализовать? Ведь объект User не может владеть другим объектом User через модель Shipment - или я чего то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте связь `belongs_to :friendship` в модель `Shipment`, а выборку отфильтруйте по друзьям создателя. Дальше работайте с этой связью.

Comment: Согласен, там видимо переборщил. Переделал с предыдущего коммита - все равно ошибка.